# swift image data from file Operation not permitted

Tags: swift, file

i got this error when trying to get image data from local file

```
NSUnderlyingError=0x28098d0b0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"
```

fileURL :

```
"file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0123.JPG"
```

here is code:

```
if imageName.contains("file"){
            do {
                let fileURL = URL(string: imageName)!
                let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
                backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            } catch {
                print("Error loading image : \(error)")
            }
        }else{
            backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        }
```

can someone give me some advices?

Comment: How are you getting this file URL?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez from imagepicker